# GLSL, only vec4 is tightly packed?

Tags: c++, glsl

Reading the book *opengl superbible*, i found this section:

> In particular, this means that arrays of anything but **vec4** (and N × 4 matrices) won’t be tightly packed, but instead there will be a gap between each of the elements.

So is this something, which can't be changed, and only `vec4` is tightly packed?

Comment: I think it might be relevant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment